# Why is my PVector which should remain constant being modified in this sketch

Tags: java, processing

I am building a sketch which at the moment has two classes; walkers and emitters. The walkers do a random perlin-noise walk and fade out over time. The emitters are meant to be the points at which the walkers are emitted and have a PVector 'position' describing the emitter location and a float 'density' describing the density of walkers emitted per frame of animation.

I have two problems. The first and most serious problem is that for some reason the position PVector in my emitter class is varying over time (looks as if I'm somehow making it also randomly walk). How is this happening? Notice in the emit() method I have a commented line which forces the same PVector each time and this works precisely as intended.

The second problem is that the walkers seem to have a tendency to both drift on a north-easterly bearing and also seem to be loosely bound in a square. I have no idea what causes this behavior so any insights would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

CODE:

```
ArrayList<Walker> walkers;
ArrayList<Emitter> emitters;
int tmax = 1200;
int stepSize = 2;

int nWalkers = 50;

void setup(){
  size(1024,1024);
  frameRate(60);
  walkers = new ArrayList<Walker>();
  emitters = new ArrayList<Emitter>();
  emitters.add(new Emitter(new PVector(width/2, height/2), 0.5));



}


void draw() {

  for (Emitter e: emitters){
  e.emit(); 
  }

  fill(255, 50); // alpha will control fade-out (agaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaain)
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, width, height); // Creates fading tail for walkers


  for(int i = walkers.size() - 1; i>=0; i--){
    Walker w = (Walker) walkers.get(i);
    if(w.time > tmax) {
    walkers.remove(i);

    }
    w.walk();
    w.displayline();


  }

}

class Emitter {
  PVector position;
  float density;

  Emitter(PVector positionIni,  float densityIni) {
  position = positionIni;
  density = densityIni;

  }

  void emit() {

    if(random(1000) > map(density, 0, 1, 0, 1000)) {
      walkers.add(new Walker(position, new PVector(random(-10,10), random(-10,10)))); // DOESN'T WORK
      //walkers.add(new Walker(new PVector(width/2, height/2), new PVector(random(-10,10), random(-10,10))));
    }
  }


}



class Walker {
  PVector location, plocation;
  PVector noff, step;
  int time;

  Walker(PVector locationIni, PVector noffIni) {
    location = locationIni;
    plocation = new PVector(location.x, location.y);
    noff = noffIni;
    step = new PVector(map(noise(noff.x), 0, 1, -stepSize, stepSize), map(noise(noff.y), 0, 1, -stepSize, stepSize));
    time = 0;
  }

  void displayline() {
    strokeWeight(1);
    fill(map(time, 0, tmax, 0, 255));
    stroke(map(time, 0, tmax, 0, 255));
    //ellipse(location.x, location.y,1,1);
    line(plocation.x, plocation.y,location.x, location.y);
    time++;

  }
  void walk() {


    plocation.x = location.x;
    plocation.y = location.y;

    step.x = map(noise(noff.x), 0, 1, -stepSize, stepSize);
    step.y = map(noise(noff.y), 0, 1, -stepSize, stepSize);

    location.add(step);

    noff.x += 0.05;
    noff.y += 0.05;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two problems. The first and most serious problem is that for some reason the position PVector in my emitter class is varying over time (looks as if I'm somehow making it also randomly walk). How is this happening? Notice in the emit() method I have a commented line which forces the same PVector each time and this works precisely as intended.

You've described the problem exactly. You're passing in the `position` variable to your `Walker` class, and then the `Walker` class is changing that `PVector` in this line:

```
location.add(step);
```

Since you're changing the variable passed in, you're changing the original `position` variable. That's why it works fine if you pass in a different `PVector` instance.

To fix this problem, you might want to see the `copy()` function of the `PVector` class. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_copy_.html).

> The second problem is that the walkers seem to have a tendency to both drift on a north-easterly bearing and also seem to be loosely bound in a square.

The square is happening because your max bounds are a square. Think about the maximum possible values your positions could take. That forms a square, so if you have a bunch of positions in that square, you'll start to see the square shape. To fix this, you'll have to use some basic trigonometry to make the maximum a circle instead. Basically: store a heading and a velocity, and then use `cos()` and `sin()` to calculate the position. Google is your friend here.

If you notice them moving towards a direction, that means your random number generation is off. Try splitting this line up into multiple steps to track down exactly where that bias comes from:

```
step = new PVector(map(noise(noff.x), 0, 1, -stepSize, stepSize), map(noise(noff.y), 0, 1, -stepSize, stepSize));
```

Comment: Actually I know the naming is confusing but the location PVector is for the location of the walkers and the position PVector is for the emitter. I managed to work around the bug via

    walkers.add(new Walker(new PVector(position.x, position.y), new PVector(random(-10,10), random(-10,10))));

Instead of passing position wholesale.

Thanks for the other advice about the random number generation I will look into this

Comment: @niklz The naming isn't confusing. It doesn't matter if you gave your variables two different names. **They're pointing to the same object.** Changing one of them changes the other. Your solution of creating a new `PVector` is doing the exact same thing as my suggestion of using the `copy()` function, just with more code. :p

Comment: Ooooh right. Thanks I didn't know the variables worked that way!

Comment: @niklz For a really great explanation, I highly recommend reading [Cup Size - a story about variables](http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryCups.jsp) and its follow up [Pass-by-Value Please (Cup Size continued)](http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp).